# Why isn't the form sending the text value from my form?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I'm following a tutorial to create a simple todo app using the MEAN stack. Everything was working fine until I moved the controllers and services into separate files. Now I can create a new todo but it doesn't get the text value. I can see in my mongoDB database that a new entry has been created but it doesn't have a text value. I've been looking all over my code but I can't find anything nor do I get any error or warnings in the developer tools of the browser. 
Here is the code for the form:

```
<div id="todo-form" class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Bind this value to formData.text in Angular -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="Add a todo" ng-model="formData.text">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createTodo()">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my service:

```
 //todos.js service
//the service is meant to interact with our api
angular.module('todoService', [])
  //simple service
  //each function returns a promise object
  .factory('Todos', function($http){
    return {
      get : function() {
        return $http.get('/api/todos');
      },
      create : function(todoData){
        return $http.post('/api/todos', todoData);
      },
      delete : function(id){
        return $http.delete('/api/todos/' + id);
      }
    }
  });
```

Here is my main controller which uses the service:

```
    //main.js
var myApp = angular.module('todoController', []);
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Todos', function($scope, $http, Todos){
  $scope.formData = {};

  //GET
  //get all the todos by using the service we created
  Todos.get()
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.todos = data;
    });
  //CREATE
  $scope.createTodo = function(){
    Todos.create($scope.formData)
          .success(function(data){
            $scope.formData = {};
            $scope.todos = data;
          });
    }

  //DELETE
  $scope.deleteTodo = function(id){
    Todos.delete(id)
      .success(function(data){
        $scope.todos = data;
      });
  };
}]);
```

Lastly, here is the route for creating a todo:

```
var Todo = require('./models/todos');

//expose our routes to our app with module exports
module.exports = function(app){
  //api
  //get all todos
  app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res){
    Todo.find(function(err, todos){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(todos);
    });
  });

  //create to do
  app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res){
    Todo.create({
      text: req.body.text,
      done: false
    }, function(err, todo){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);

      //get and return all todos after creating the new one
      Todo.find(function(err, todos){
        if(err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json(todos);
      });
    });
  });
```

To recap, for some reason the formData.text value doesn't get stored somewhere and I don't know why.

Comment: What errors on the browser's console? You mentioned also that it was working before you put controllers and services in separate files. Did you link those files in the correct order so modules are loaded in the correct order?

Comment: I mean I don't get any errors in the browser when I open the developer tools, so I don't have an error in the code. Yes, the linking in my index file is being done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure with angular but normal HTML forms inputs need a name attribute to submit